# Memory Warning error from Cache Images

Tags: iphone, crash

I am storing high resolution images in iPhone cache . I am getting Memory warning and the app is crashing.

Please help me how to handle crash ?

Comment: Poor question. Poor answer: Use less memory or clear memory you aren't using.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the image size and save it. The below method reduces the size of the image.
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(YOUR_IMAGE_OBJECT, 0.0);
The second parameter decides the quality and size of the image. It changes from 0.0 to 1.0.
Please try this